# C# webservice v/s VB.net webservice

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, vb.net-2010

What is the best language to develop a webservice whether C# webservice or VB.net webservice. 
Both use XML to communicate. 
SOAP is used to transfer the data,
WSDL is used for describing the services 
UDDI is used to get a list of services available. 
But what difference does it make to develop webservice in C# or VB.net ?

Comment: Whenever you ask for “best” be sure to be very specific what is this “best” you’re talking about. And preferably never use that word, rather explain the situation. Now you haven’t given any specifications so there is no possible way to say what is “best” other than opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is the syntax. use your favorite syntax. Already, your vb or c# code compile to IL/CIL/MSIL code.

- VB->CLR(Common Language Runtime)->IL code
- C#->CLR(Common Language Runtime)->IL code

Answer (score 1):

There are no **relevant** differences for your case.

As long as you stay with the .NET framework you can always choose between VB & C#.

They real question you should ask is: **What .NET framework should I use?** .NET Core 2 or .NET 4.7? This makes a much more relevant difference.

Comment: What can produce collision issues during event listener?

Comment: I don't understand the question and where it comes from?

Comment: In the webservice, i am going to create, it will have listeners implemented. The common problem with listeners is that it produces collision issues. So, can i create better listener with C# or with VB.net ?

Comment: I don't think thats an C# or VB issue. Its more of a framework thing.